# Congruence properties

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

In congruence, we have this property:

(a ≡ b (mod m) and 0 ≤ b < m) ⇒ a = m . q + b

This says that for this

a ≡ b (mod m) and 0 ≤ b < m

We have that b is the remainder in the Euclidean division of a by m.

By the way, we also that another property:

a ≡ b (mod m) ⇒ a and b have the same remainder in the Euclidean division by m.

Proof:

Euclidean division of a by m is a = m . k + r

By a ≡ b (mod m) we have: a = m . q + b

If we substitute a of the second equation in first, we have:

m . q + b = m . k + r ⇒ b = m .k + r - m . q ⇒ b = m(k - q) + r

Then the remainder of the Euclidean division of a and b by m, is the same!

But with these two properties together should we don't conclude wrongly that a is equal to b? by the symmetry of congruence

Comment: Why would you think that?  $3\equiv 1 \pmod 2$ and $0≤1<2$, but $3\neq 1$.

Comment: I know that, but the properties don't look to say it. If the rest of the division of a by m is b, and congruence is symmetric, then the rest of the division of b by m is a. Although the rest of the division of a and b by m is the same, then a and b should be equal. I want to know where I'm wrong in assume this.

Comment: The mathematical definition of $a\equiv b \pmod m$ is that $m\,|\,(a-b)$. It is often convenient (for programming, say) to let, say, $a\pmod m$ denote the remainder of $a$ on division by $m$ but if you use that definition then it is not true that $a\pmod m=b\implies b\pmod m=a$.  You just need to be clear about what your terminology means.